# NSMutableDictionary writeToFile fails with more than one item

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary, writetofile

i've googled all over about this, couldn't find a solution: I an using a standard NSMutableDictionary writeToFile method which keeps failing if my dictionary has MORE THAN ONE item, containing a "thumbnailURL" key, but it doesn't fail if I comment out the use of this particular key and leave all the rest... My dict contains other NSMutableDictionaries, each containing 2 NSStrings: "title" and "thumbnailURL" keys. The keys are all NSString.

At first, the dict is empty, so I simply add to it:

```
NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary* entry = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [thumbnailURL absoluteString], @"thumbnailURL",
                       title, @"title",
                       nil];
[d setObject:entry forKey:guid];
[d writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; // returns YES on first attempt
```

Later, I load the dict:

```
NSMutableDictionary* d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

The above also works according to the debugger, I can see the item I saved.
Next, I add another item, identical to the previous one, except for the guid key.
The debugger shows the item is stored properly in the dict object in memory.
Finally, I try to save it again with the same code - it fails, writeToFile returns NO.

If I comment out the "thumbnailURL" key and leave only the "title", it works, no errors...

Any idea?
tnx

Answer (score 1):

ok, found the issue, it's a bug on my end, when I load the dictionary between saves, I convert to NSURL again and I forgot to reconvert it back to NSString on the second save... The debugger didn't catch it because it shows the same thumbnailURL description for NSURL and NSString...